# How Do I Create a Production Client Authentication Certificate for Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, client-certificates, azure-keyvault

I am learning about [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/), and one of the scenarios it supports is certificate authentication, [which you can read about here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/#authenticate-with-a-certificate-instead-of-a-client-secret).

The samples do a great job of explaining how to make a self-signed certificate for local testing, which I have gotten to work without an issue.  My question now is, how do I go about making a certificate for production deployments?  Do I purchase this from a service somewhere?  If so, what type of certificate do I need, exactly?

Unfortunately, there is no documentation anywhere that I could find in Azure Key Vault that outlines how to make (or what is expected/assumed) in a production-level certificate.

I basically have a few requirements/expectations based on my research/investigation so far:

1. I would like to use a trusted, external service (CA?) to purchase the certificate from.
2. The cheaper the certificate the better. :)
3. [I would like to be able to create a certificate with custom data extensions.](http://the.randomengineer.com/2014/04/18/adding-custom-data-to-x-509-ssl-certificates/)

In addition to my requirements, I have a specific question in regards to the certificate: **What type of certificate do I need?**  Is this a server authentication certificate?  Or a client authentication certificate? Or... ?

I have spent the past hour going through several SSL certificate providers, but none of them really could give me a great answer for the type of certificate I am looking for (when I provided the link to Azure certificate above to them).  So, I decided to do what I should have done in the first place, and put my question up here to the esteemed community. :)

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cert for SSL you want to get a Server Authentication certificate (it proves that the server, ie your site, is who it claims to be).

You can buy it from any trusted service and upload it to Azure Key Vault.  Just google "buy ssl certificate".  I think you can get one for as little as $30 if I remember correctly.

Comment: I have done that, but I have not had any success with finding one that will allow me to provide custom data extensions (requirement #3 above).  And also, I do not know if you can upload a certificate to AKV?  You can upload it to Azure Active Directory, I know.  Please provide a reference if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key Vault to enroll for certificate from public CAs such as DigiCert and GlobalSign. Look at the "Enroll programmatically from Public CA" section in https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/

You can use the Key Vault REST API to programmatically enroll for certificates -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/createcertificate

The certificate policy allows for some customization like specifying which KeyUsage and EKUs you want in your certificate.